# Apply breeze predicate to data in an observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am executing breeze queries for my entities and storing the data in browser local cache.
If I happen to load these entities in future, instead of executing the breeze query again I am loading the data from local storage into observable arrays.
I was wondering how can I filter data in these observable arrays by applying breeze predicates since I won't be executing breeze queries again.

Is it possible to apply breeze predicates on an observable array to filter data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze has the ability to [execute your query locally](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQueryLocally).  For this to work you'll need to load the data from local storage into a breeze entity manager.  There are several ways to do this ([importEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_importEntities), [attachEntity](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_attachEntity)), the approach depends on how you are storing and retrieving your entities from local storage.  It would make your life easier if you used [exportEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_exportEntities) and [importEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_importEntities) when storing/retrieving entity data from local storage.  If you do choose to use exportEntites, pay careful attention to the `includeMetadata` argument.  You may want to cache the metadata separately to save space.